# numpy block scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
row_num=24983
col_size = 102
arr = np.zeros((row_num,col_num))
arr[:,0]= np.arange(row_num)
```

When I write it, it gives me scientific notation array like,

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       ..., 
       [  2.49800000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.49810000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.49820000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

but I don't desire it. I'm wanting normal numpy array like,

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 24980.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 24981.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 24982.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Edit: I know np.set_printoptions but I'll write the array to a csv file and when I do it it still writing with scientific notation to file. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the way the array is displayed, you could use [np.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) to set a float formatting function:

```
In [13]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{:g}'.format})

In [14]: arr
Out[14]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [24980, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [24981, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [24982, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

The meaning of the `g` format is [described here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). While the `g` format generally succeeds in presenting simple floats in a humanly readable way without exponential notation, it does not guarantee that exponential notation is never used.

Therefore, you might instead use the `f` format,
e.g. `np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{:.2f}'.format})` if you wish to
present all floats with a fixed level of precision. This guarantees that no exponential notation is used.

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
In [25]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

In [26]: arr
Out[26]: 
array([[     0.,      0.,      0., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.],
       [     1.,      0.,      0., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.],
       [     2.,      0.,      0., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.],
       ..., 
       [ 24980.,      0.,      0., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.],
       [ 24981.,      0.,      0., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.],
       [ 24982.,      0.,      0., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.]])
```

`suppress=True` tells `np.set_printoptions` to suppress the printing of small floating point values using scientific notations.

---

To create a CSV file use

```
np.savetxt(filename, arr, fmt='%g')
```

[The `fmt` parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) allows you to control the float format using [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Comment: thanks, it's working on terminal but, in addition to this, I'll write the array to a csv file and when I do it it still writing with scientific notation

Comment: Use `np.savetxt(filename, arr, fmt='%g')` to create the CSV. The `fmt` parameter allows you to control the float format.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the `g` format presents floats in simple, humanly readable format when possible. The `G` format is the same a `g` except that a capital `E` is used instead of a small `e` when exponential format is required.